# JS / Prototype - Detect SELECT element collapsed or option actually selected

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have functionality setup to execute whenever a select element changes its value. Instead of using the normal onchange event, it executes every 300ms and only calls the handler if it detects a changed value. I'm using prototype's `Form.Element.Observer`, if this means anything to you.

Now, in Firefox, when the user hovers over the `option` and the timed value check function fires, the handler is called because the browser says that the value has changed. What I would like to do is be able to detect when the option has actually been selected by the user instead of simply hovered over. I realize in the Prototype documentation, they explicitly note this bug (or feature, depending how you look at it) but I would like to be able to normalize the behavior.

In a way, this is somewhat similar to a question I've seen on StackOverflow before ( [Detect if an HTML select element is expanded (without manually tracking state)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156574/detect-if-an-html-select-element-is-expanded-without-manually-tracking-state) ) but I was hoping someone out there would be able to tell me how to do this for only a specific select element and when it's closed instead of expanded.

To get a better idea of what I mean, check out http://jsfiddle.net/KxQd6/ , mess with the select element and check out the console logs.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the `onchange` event, what is your use-case?

Comment: `onchange` will only fire when the user changes the value. There are a lot of times when I have js change the value and I need those to be detected as well. A typical use case is for conditional form elements. A user selects the value (or on form submission or ajax callback, the value is supplied by the server) and certain content is enabled / disabled.

Comment: Then when those values are returned from the server, you can fire the `onchange`, do you have control over that? if so I can help you do that

Comment: The only other way that the fields can change is through being updated via javascript. If you know a solution that can handle those three cases of updates (user, dom-load, and js update) that doesn't involve an observer or extensive code maintenance, in all seriousness, I would love to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing how to control `SELECT` element changes through the different stages you mentioned:

> (user, dom-load, and js update)

This code utilizes [`event.simulate`](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js) which provides a cross browser way of firing/simulating events.

---

**CODE** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/4LGee/))

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var select = $('box_1'),
        button_1 = $('change_via_ajax'), 
        button_2 = $('change_via_script'), 
        results = $('results');

    // create observer on our select
    select.observe('change', function(e) {
        var d = new Date()
            t = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
        results.insert(new Element('div')
               .update(t + ' - Change was fired, value is now [' + this.value + ']'));
    });

    button_1.observe('click', function() {
        new Ajax.Request('/echo/json/', {
            onComplete: function(j) {
                select.options[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)].selected = true;
                select.simulate('change');
            }
        });
    });

    button_2.observe('click', function() {
        select.options[0].selected = true;
        select.simulate('change');
    });
});​
```

Comment: I've used event.simulate for other things in the past. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks!

This seems like the most reasonable solution to the issue I'm having. The only thing is that, whenever I change the value of a select element, I also have to call the `simulate` method. Ideally, I'd like to just change the value of the element and it would know to call its `onchange` method. I suppose that's what got me into this mess in the first place though. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen (especially at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/coffee/chosen.proto.coffee lines 68-89). There is no way to determine current state of SELECT element - only to track it more or less reliably with a bunch of event observers for mouse, keyboard and UI events.