# how to trigger function onchange on already selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  dropdown which i would like to trigger a function when something is selected.

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>

$(document).on("change", "#myselect", function(event) {
alert("you selected something");
});
```

The problem I have is that the function is not triggered if i choose option that has already been selected. I do understand that this is because nothing has been changed but is there a way around this?

I have tried

```
  <select id="myselect" onmousedown="this.value='';" >
```

this was ok for the few options, but when i had many options when i needed to scroll down to select it would jump up and select the wrong option.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger jQuery change event on dropdown with same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108203/how-to-trigger-jquery-change-event-on-dropdown-with-same-value)

Comment: none of the answers have solved the problem

Comment: Have you read my response ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <select id="myselect" onclick="alert('Something selected')">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).on("change", ".myselect",function(){
    var idSelect = $(this).attr("id"); /*get the id select change*/
    $(".myselect").each(function(){
       var idSelectOther = $(this).attr("id");/*get the id of another select*/
       if(idSelect != idSelectOther){ /*if id selected != other select then check value*/
          if($("#"+idSelect).val() == $("#"+idSelectOther).val()){ /* if val same so alert the user.*/
            alert("you already select this value");
          }
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect" id="sel1">
  <option val="1">1</option>
  <option val="2">2</option>
  <option val="3">3</option>
 </select>
 
 <select class="myselect"  id="sel2">
  <option val="1">1</option>
  <option val="2">2</option>
  <option val="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: this does not allow me to select anything

Comment: i Update my answer, are that you looking for?